# Is it usual that almost 25% of all set flags don't get processed?

Tags: discussion

Almost 25% of all my flags have been aged away, that's quite a lot and really sad since I put at least some effort in it to help cleaning up SO. So I am wondering, is it usual that so many flags are not handled?

*Note:* All these flags have been set in the past 6 months and are mostly oriented around `C#`. Am I in a quite busy period of moderators/reviewers or is it hard handling flags around one of the most active tag? What can I change about this situation? Those reviews I am allowed to process, I always have a look at.

[image]

Comment: Yes, when you generally tend to vote to close in low-traffic tags or to close posts others don't think need closing.

Comment: Put differently: **all** flags that have aged away are flags to close a post.

Comment: Yes, it is usual. I'm in the same situation.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, ok. So does SO work this way: If I set a close vote and not enough users do so as well in a *specific period of time* the flag ages away?

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes Ok, that's quite sad though. Does decrease my effort on flagging since it doesn't change anything then. Or rather not to close vote on low-traffic tags that much.

Comment: I believe it's still worth flagging tho. Even if it doesn't change a thing, it feels good to know that I made some effort to improve stackoverflow... On other hand: I have enough rep to use close votes now, so I only flag answers (no more question flags). And those are marked as helpful very often.

Comment: That's true the feeling to help improving SO is the motivation why I try to flag a lot. Ok that's something different, I haven't reached that permission yet. But I think I will focus then more on high-traffic tags.

Comment: When it comes to this site keep in mind that there is a lot to moderate; a **lot**. If a particular action is known to yield no results... I wouldn't waste my time continuing to do it and spend your time on things that do make a difference. So don't feel ashamed to shift your focus to other tags.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your opinion. Will keep that in mind for choosing a topic to focus on.